# How To Handle Large Files Using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Im working with very large files and using Spring Integration to process them. I want to know what is the best and most efficient way to handle them using Spring Integration and the provided DSL. I have a test CSV file that has around 30K records and am using the `FileSplitter` component to read in each line into memory and then splitting again based on the delimiter to get the columns that I need.

Code snippet below.

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(inputFilePath))
                    .filter(getFileFilters())
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true) ,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000))
                    
                    )
            
            .split(Files.splitter())
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newWorkStealingPool()))
            .handle((p, h) -> new MyColumnSelector().getCol((String) p, 1))
            .split(s -> s.applySequence(true).delimiters(","))
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newWorkStealingPool()))
            .get()
```

Comment: Share, please, with us what’s the problem are facing? Doesn’t look like you ask any question and also your code provides some solution. What kind of help are you seeking? What makes you thinking your solution is not efficient ?

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for your response. I realized that my issue was just the IDE and the logging overhead that was slowing things down. I tested this with the same file without any logging and without my IDE and it processed significantly faster. Thanks again.

Comment: Good. You can form that as an answer for your own question to let people know what is going on. Because yeah, at a glance I didn’t see any issues with your config…

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the IDE and console logging overhead that was slowing things down. I tested this with the same file without any the IDE or any extra logging and it processed significantly faster.